# MySQL commands history

Tags: mysql, logging, history

When using `mysql` through command line (with default shipped configuration), I was able to get my commands history using up-arrow.
 Bu after modifying the server configuration for a remote access and successfully authenticated to, I'm not able to view any command and it feels annoying thinking that I lost all my commands history.

Is there some location where mysql stores previously used commands?

BR.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On Unix, the mysql client logs statements executed interactively to a history file. By default, this file is named `.mysql_history` in your home directory.

Please read out [**MySQL Documentation.**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-logging.html)

Comment: I'm aware of the existance of such a file if I didn't mention it, sorry. But it is nothing but a blank page after editing the mysql server configurations...